# Como tratar uma "birrinha"

Tags: suporte

Este caso acredito que alguns já sofreram e/ou presenciaram, que é o downvote por "birra".

Vi uma pergunta simples, olhei a resposta, e estava incorreta, então dei o downvote, e comentei o motivo.

Fiz certo no downvote !? Acredito que sim !

Então no mesmo tempo, postei a minha resposta corretamente, e a pessoa percebeu que fui eu quem dei o -1 e também deu em minha resposta:

[image: print]

Além do downvote, tomei um "obrigado" sarcástico ! (para mim engraçado, porém, prejudicial a comunidade)

Como proceder nesses tipos de atitude ?

Comment: Votos são e sempre serão subjetivos, independente se for positivo ou negativo. São raras as ocasiões em que se percebe os propósitos de tais votos. Até não entender, devemos seguir o protocolo do *tooltip* nas setinhas do seu post. Você fez o correto e o que sempre terá de fazer quando isso ocorrer: vir ao meta e descrever a situação. Só os moderadores poderão analisar, entender o problema e se possível tomar alguma providência.

Comment: @bio eu já acho que se tem muito voto negativo incorreto, e isso agrava por falta de justificativa (o que pelo visto nunca terá ! rs)

Comment: Se você fazer uma [pesquisa sobre votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=votos+negativos) verá que existem inúmeros casos e discussões sobre isso. Infelizmente a ferramenta não é perfeita (como qualquer outra) e existe essa burocracia para resolver esses problemas. Se eu fosse criar uma pergunta pra cada negativo que eu recebi em minhas perguntas e respostas eu estaria utilizando mais o Meta do que o SOpt. Seu caso é raro pois o autor do negativo pessoal se revelou e ficou fácil de tomar uma providência, mas em outros casos isso é quase impossível...

Comment: @bio sim, exatamente isso, raro ele se identificar, mas eu também não estou preocupado com o voto para mim (tanto que tampei o nome do usuário, mas sim porque o cara acostuma, e "atrapalha" a ferramenta e quem quer ajudar. Mas achei que poderia haver um tipo de sinalização. Como não tem, então fica por isso mesmo.

Comment: Em alguns anos de rede, a melhor atitude que eu achei é ignorar essas figuras sempre que possível. Muita perda de tempo por coisa sem peso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não ligue pra isso. O que mais tem são usuários com o dedo *pesado* para dar *downvote* sem ao menos deixar o motivo. É como se estivessem sempre ávidos pra votar negativo.

Você fez certíssimo, em dar o *down* e ainda deixar o motivo. Parabéns! Poucos usuários fazem isso. Mas eu seria um pouco mais tolerante: antes de dar o *down*, deixaria uma mensagem alertando o problema, e depois voltava lá e, caso não houvesse resposta ou mudança, aí sim o *down*.

Mas é o velho assunto já abordado muitas vezes: a subjetividade do voto. Cada um vota como quer, não tem como julgar de forma categórica que foi "vingança". Você pode ter a suspeita de que, como mesmo disse:

> [...]a pessoa percebeu que fui eu quem dei o -1 e também deu em minha
>   resposta..

Como você sabe que foi esse usuário? O melhor é a consciência tranquila de que você contribuiu de forma positiva postando uma resposta correta. Se recebeu -1 por vingança, inveja ou sei lá o que, faça vista grossa pra isso. Usuários com esse tipo de comportamento geralmente não são usuários assíduos e, tenho certeza, sua resposta será valorizada.

Quanto a "tratar uma birrinha", não entre nessa. Se o usuário quiser entrar nesse *jogo*, dê apenas uma resposta educada e esqueça-o, deixe-o falando sozinho. Em qualquer comunidade, principalmente online, tem muita gente mal educada que se esconde atrás do monitor. Mas os rastros são deixados e todos irão ver quem está levando a sério ou não a comunidade.

Comment: Concordo com você em tudo. Eu só dei o -1 junto ao comentário, porque acho que fica como uma forma de "obrigar" o cara corrigir. Assim após ele fazer a correção, eu tiro, aí ele começa a "pensar de outra forma" sobre o voto negativo. Como também tem os que adoram dar downvote sem motivo, tem os que dão upvote também, e acabam dando na resposta do cara sem ao menos ver se funcionava. Uma coisa interessante é: o cara não sabe o que significa um downvote, mas ele sabe dar uma "olhadinha" no perfil dos outros para saber quem deu o down pra ele ! rs

Comment: A pergunta foi mais para saber se tinha alguma forma de tratar isso, tipo sinalizar, etc. Mas como não tem, sem problemas ! rs

Comment: Mas por mim está tranquilo. Eu poderia tomar quantos downvotes quiserem todos os dias, que só irão tirar minha reputação no SO. Mas tudo o que eu aprendi, isso ninguém tira mais ! :)